# Web Notification API with onClick after page close

Tags: javascript

I have experienced web notification, it's great. It's awesome that you can have a on click event listener on them as well.

I have encounter an issue, when the page close, the on click event on the notification is gone.

Try the link below:

jsfiddle.net/yoshi6jp/Umc9A/

There is an on click event on the notification to open a new tab, but if you close the page and try to click on the notification again it just wont work.

Is there a way you can store the eventlistner on the notification even the page closed.

Comment: no, the handler lives in the page's dom. the click event is deprecated anyway, it should just focus the calling tab now and in the future.

Comment: @dandavis thanks mate, what do you mean ->  it should just focus the calling tab now and in the future.?